# How do you trust a client?

Tags: security, networking, architecture

I am working on a game where the world simulation is performed on clients. These clients submit updated world state to a central server. That server then redistributes those changes to the rest of those clients. Simple.

The issue is, I want to protect against modified clients. That is, I want to prevent cheaters that modify variables or whatnot in the executable.

At first I thought I would use a public key/private key encryption scheme. All commands sent from the client would be encrypted and sent to the server. But I quickly realized that this doesn't offer any real protection against cheaters since they can still modify variables.

The only other solution I can think of is to store all variables in a file and to record a hash of it. Then the client can only update the server after the server verifies these hashes.

But then I realized that a cheater could just rewrite the network request to patch those hashes.

I don't know where to go from here.

What protocols can be put in place so that the server only accepts commands from trusted (i.e. known) code bases?

Comment: "How do you trust a client?" Pro tip: you don't.

Comment: @PeeHaa that's fair! Thought I would ask.

Comment: You can do things to make the client more secure, but rule #1 of client/server remains: "Never trust the client".

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to be so pessimist. Do your best to avoid cheaters to modify your data. For example one of common ways is to inject a DLL to game process and modify data on memory. Most game trainers do it in this way. You can periodically check your process's loaded modules and exit if there is unknown module. You may think of game's internet connection. Well, do your best. Add encryption and some custom handshake algorithms to make it complex and hard for cheaters.

In general, there is a lot of things which you can do to make your game hard-to-cheat.